# How to output VM Guest Hard Disk information in comma separated string using PowerCli

Tags: powershell, powercli, vcenter

This is hopefully a very simple problem but with my limited knowledge of Powershell and Powercli, it is difficult for me. I am trying to produce a csv file with lot of information about our VMs. One of the piece is hard disk path and capacity. It is available using VMGuest.disks property. Since, I want to display all disk information in one column, I use following to put information in one field called diskinfo.

```
$DiskArr = $VMGuest.Disks | Select @{Name="DiskInfo";Expression={$_.path + " -- " + $_.CapacityGB }}
```

What I was hoping is that

```
 $DiskArr -join ","
```

will give me result like c:\ -- 50.xxxxx GB, D:\ -- 32.000 GB and so on. But it gives me blanks with comma separated like ,,,, for four disks.

What am I missing?

Comment: `$DiskArr -join ","`  -> `$DiskArr.DiskInfo -join ","`

Comment: Great. That is exactly what I was missing :) Thank you so much. Please add this comment as an answer so that I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided in comments by Ben H. I am merely copying his answer:

```
 $DiskArr -join ","
```

was changed to

```
 $DiskArr.DiskInfo -join ","
```

Essentially problem was missing property name. I was providing object but without any property reference.